# (MS)SQL execute query with additional varchar/text in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Hi guys is something like that possible in SQL.

```
declare a as varchar(20)
set a = 'ID = 34 and ID = 22'

select * from something where ID = 1 and a
```

Comment: You can, as others have said, with `EXEC`, but you almost certainly shouldn't. Wanting to do something like this is normally an indicator of a flawed design.

Comment: Don't use EXEC for stuff like this. SQL Server includes Table Valued types so you can pass a list into a stored proc as a parameter -- then you treat that list as a table inside the stored proc. its way, way safer and gives the optimizer much more scope for caching your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `exec` for that - concatenating strings to one and then running an SQL query of that string.

So in your case it would be:

```
declare @a varchar(20)
set @a = 'ID = 34 and ID = 22'
exec ('select * from something where ID = 1 and ' + @a)
```

Just be careful of SQL injections.

Comment: You're answer is so much like mine but has more text around it. +1 for that!

Comment: gah -- dynamic sql for the fail. but at least you warned about the injection. SQL server has table valued types for exactly this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use use `EXEC`

```
declare @a as varchar(20)
set @a = 'ID = 34 and ID = 22'

EXEC ('select * from something where ID = 1 and ' + @a)
```

Warning: this type of concatenating SQL queries is a security risk because of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: At least warn about all the security problems with sql injection.

Comment: @TransactCharlie Very true!

Answer (score 1):

put them into a table value (or even a temp table) and join to them. you can even use an index. (though with a few values an index is probably not going to help much!)

Avoids all the possible security complications of sql injection and is generally nicer.

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT @ids VALUES (1),(2)

SELECT s.*
FROM
    someTable AS s
    JOIN @ids AS i ON i.ID = s.ID
```

Check out user defined table types for a better way to pass lists to stored procs.

Also check out this page for the *definitive* answer to questions like this: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html